# Have a solution of an equation system but don't know how to "prove" it

Tags: analysis

Solve the equation system where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

$x+yz=2016$
$xy+z=2015$

The only solution I get is when $y=0$, $x=2016$ and $z=2015$ but I don't know how to "prove" it.

Comment: Substract the equations to get $z=x-1$. This has been already posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125482/solving-equations?rq=1).

Comment: Do you have trouble proving that what you have is a solution, or are you having trouble showing that it's the only one? (If it _is_ the only one, that is.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I don't see it. Are you perhaps confusing $yz$ with $xy$?

Answer (score 3):

Subtract the second from the first to obtain $$x(1-y)-z(1-y)=1$$

This tells us that $(1-y)\,|\,1$ so $1-y=\pm 1$.  Hence $y\in \{0,2\}$.

If $y=0$ we get the case you mentioned.

If $y=2$ we get $$x+2z=2016\quad \& \quad 2x+z=2015\implies z=672.\overline 3$$

As that is not an integer we are left with the case you identified.